# Symfony: access property of EntityManagerDecorator

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, decorator, symfony4

I need to decorate an Symfony EntityManager and access a property that I inject in it from ouside, but it always says that this is Undefined Property.

This is config:

```
    app.decorated.doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager:
    class: App\Decorator\EntityManager
    public: false
    decorates: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
    arguments:
        - "@app.decorated.doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager.inner"
        - '%photo_directory_absolute%'
```

So for example Im passing value '%photo_directory_absolute%'

This is part of decorator:

```
    namespace App\Decorator;
    class EntityManager extends EntityManagerDecorator
    {
        public $photoDir;
        public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $wrapped, string $photoDir)
        {
            parent::__construct($wrapped);
            $this->photoDir = $photoDir;    
        }
```

Then I want to get this 'photoDir' value from Hydrator

```
namespace App\Hydrator;

class UserAppHydrator  extends ObjectHydrator
{   
    protected function hydrateRowData(array $data, array &$result)
    {
        $hydrated_result = array();
        parent::hydrateRowData($data, $hydrated_result);

       die(var_dump($this->_em->photoDir));
```

And this shows me an error :

```
"Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityManager::$photoDir"
```

What I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Seems like your decorator is not being registered

Comment: I think it is because if I write for example die(var_dump($photoDir)); in constructor of EntityManagerDecorator it fires with correct value.

Comment: But the error references the class EntityManager, not your decorator class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the method `newHydrator` of the `EntityManagerDecorator` to get your `EntityManager` injected into a `Hydrator`. If that is missing, the `$wrapped` instance will be used.